# Append to list in dictionary without replacing old value?

Tags: python

So I have lists in the format:

```
[2.7, 2018, Canada]
[3.4, 2018, New York, USA]
[17.49, 2017, Canada]
```

This pattern continues for a while with countries repeating.

I want to put it in the format:

```
{Canada: [2018, 2.7, 2017, 17.49], USA: [2018, 3.4]}
```

Here's the code I got
(data_lists = the lists above)

```
empty_dic = {}
empty_dic[data_lists[-1]] = []
if data_lists[-1] in empty_dic:
    empty_dic[data_lists[-1]].append([data_lists[1], data_lists[2])

print(empty_dic)
```

However, the append function doesn't work like I want it. It overwrites the information in the previous list. Giving me an output like:

```
{Canada: [2018, 17.49], USA: [2018, 3.4]}
```

How do I make it add onto the list assigned to the key instead of replacing it?

Edit: Wanted to clarify that my data is imported from a text file in that format with the new line spacings

Comment: is your `data_lists =  [[2.7, 2018, Canada], [3.4, 2018, New York, USA], [17.49, 2017, Canada]]` ?
cause your initialization `empty_dic[data_lists[-1]] = []` is actually not right

Answer (score 3):

You can use `collections.defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict
data = [[2.7, 2018, "Canada"], [3.4, 2018, "New York", "USA"], [17.49, 2017, "Canada"]]
d = defaultdict(list)
for sublist in data:
    d[sublist[-1]] += sublist[0:2]
```

Output

```
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'USA': [3.4, 2018], 'Canada': [2.7, 2018, 17.49, 2017]})
```

Comment: How would I format my multiple lines of data from the way it is in the post to the way it's written in your comment?

Comment: @bruhsmh Where did you get the data in the original format you showed? As written it isn't valid Python syntax. Did you read it from a file like that?

Comment: Yes I got it from a text file, however all I had to do was make an empty list and append it to fix it! Also, Using this method is it possible to switch the order of values. So [2018, 2.7] instead of [2.7, 2018]?

Comment: Yes in that case to switch the values `d[sublist[-1]] += sublist[1::-1]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group lists based on common keys and then build up dict as your expected output

```
>>> import itertools
>>> data = [[2.7, 2018, "Canada"], [3.4, 2018, "New York", "USA"], [17.49, 2017, "Canada"]]
>>> d = dict((k,list(g))for k,g in itertools.groupby(sorted(data,key=lambda x: x[-1]),key=lambda x: x[-1]))
```

This operation will group lists based on common key. We have specified key to be last element of list

```
>>> d
>>> {'Canada': [[2.7, 2018, 'Canada'], [17.49, 2017, 'Canada']], 'New York': [[3.4, 2018, 'New York', 'USA']]}

>>> final_dict = dict((k,list(filter(lambda x: x!=k, list(itertools.chain(*v))))) for k,v in d.items())
```

This will give you required output

```
>>> final_dict
>>> {'Canada': [2.7, 2018, 17.49, 2017], 'New York': [3.4, 2018, 'USA']}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A = [[2.7, 2018, "Canada"], [3.4, 2018, "New York", "USA"], [17.49, 2017, "Canada"]]

d = {}
for i in A:
    if i[-1] not in d: #Check if key already in dict
        d[i[-1]] = []
    d[i[-1]] += i[:len(i)-1]   #Exclude last element

print d
```

**Result:**

```
{'Canada': [2.7, 2018, 17.49, 2017], 'USA': [3.4, 2018, 'New York']}
```